Sound Configuration Menu Disappears in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS - Cannot Change Output Codec
I’m new to Linux and encountering an issue with the sound configuration settings on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. Occasionally, the Configuration menu in the Sound settings goes missing, which prevents me from selecting or changing codecs for my output device.
I've noticed that sometimes, plugging in the USB dongle for my headset (Anker PowerConf H700) brings the Configuration menu back, allowing me to select codecs again, however this behavior is inconsistent, and I'm not sure why it disappears or how to make it permanently accessible.
Here are the details of my setup:

Ubuntu version: 24.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-45-generic
Desktop environment: GNOME 46, Wayland
Headset: Anker PowerConf H700

I would appreciate any insights or troubleshooting steps that could help me understand what’s causing this menu to disappear and how I can reliably access it to manage my audio codecs.
Menu that disappears:

